# How do I make a maze game by adapting my cocos2d-x&C++ code?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I generate a matrix about my game map by random Prim. Then I draw the map by menuItem in the cocos2d-x 4.0. I want to control a sprite to move by key "asdw". But I cannot control the sprite to cross the bamboo walls. Sometimes the sprite is  surrounded by bamboo walls.
How can I check the wall? How can I  ensure a path that the sprite can move to the destination?

This is my result image
[cross the wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPaGw.jpg)
[sprite is surrounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmvNA.jpg)

My code is below.
MazeScene.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __Maze_SCENE_H__
#define __Maze_SCENE_H__

#endif // __SECOND_SCENE_H__
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include<vector>
#include <time.h>
#define m 18  //row
#define n 10  //columns
#define down 1
#define right 2
#define left 4
#define up 8
#define WALL -1
#define NOTHING 2

USING_NS_CC;
class MazeScene : public cocos2d::Layer {
public:
Sprite* sprite;
int backgroundAudioID;
static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
virtual bool init();
void initMap();
void onReset();
void changeScene(float dt);
void update(float dt);
void GameOver();
void Success();
void onKeyPressed(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event);
void FindBlock();


CREATE_FUNC(MazeScene);
private:
struct block {
    int row, column, direction;
    block(int _row, int _column, int _direction) {
        row = _row;
        column = _column;
        direction = _direction;
    }
};
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
}start, end;

std::vector<block> myblock;
int x_num = 1, y_num = 1;//Miner location
int G[100][100];
Sprite* _player;
Sprite* _door;
Menu* mazeMenu;
int life = 180;
int i = 0;
```

};

MazeScene.cpp

```
#include "MazeScene.h"
#include <AudioEngine.h>
#include <MenuScene.h>
USING_NS_CC;
using namespace std;
#define UserDefault UserDefault::getInstance()

cocos2d::Scene* MazeScene::createScene()
{
auto scene = Scene::create();
auto  layer = MazeScene::create();
scene->addChild(layer);
return scene;
```

}

```
bool MazeScene::init()
{
if (!Layer::init())
{
    return false;
}
AudioEngine::play2d("music/leisure.mp3",true);
// special effect
auto particleSystem = ParticleSystemQuad::create("image/mist.plist");
particleSystem->setPosition(1500, 500);
this->addChild(particleSystem, 1);

auto particleSystem1 = ParticleSystemQuad::create("image/mist2.plist");
particleSystem1->setPosition(-500, 400);
this->addChild(particleSystem1, 1);


this->schedule(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(MazeScene::update), 1.0);

initMap();
return true;
}

void  MazeScene::initMap() {
//Put all the map as a wall
memset(G, WALL, sizeof(G));
//Define the starting point
G[1][1] = NOTHING;
start.x = start.y = 1;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));//Random number seed
FindBlock();
//The first step is to press into the two walls (to the right of the starting point and 
below the starting point) to enter the loop
while (myblock.size()) {
    int BlockSize = myblock.size();
    //Randomly select a wall (generate a random number between 0 and BlockSize-1, which 
    is also the subscript of the wall in the vector)
    int randnum = rand() % BlockSize;
    block SelectBlock = myblock[randnum];
    x_num = SelectBlock.row;//Miners come to our "wall of choice" here
    y_num = SelectBlock.column;
    //Follow-up operations based on the direction of the currently selected wall
    //At this time, the three areas of the wall and target block selected as the 
      starting point are on the same straight line.
    //We let the miners move on from the "wall of choice" to the "target block"
    //Miners have the ability to penetrate walls ：)
    switch (SelectBlock.direction) {
    case down: {
        x_num++;
        break;
    }
    case right: {
        y_num++;
        break;
    }
    case left: {
        y_num--;
        break;
    }
    case up: {
        x_num--;
        break;
    }
    }
    //If the target block is a wall
    if (G[x_num][y_num] == WALL) {
        //Break through the wall and target block
        G[SelectBlock.row][SelectBlock.column] = G[x_num][y_num] = NOTHING;
        //Find again the wall adjacent to the current location of the miner
        FindBlock();
    }
    else {//If not? It means that our miners have dug into an empty path and just take a 
     rest.
        //relax
    }
    //Delete this wall (delete the unusable wall, for those who have already been 
    constructed, there is no need to construct it, but also to ensure that we can jump 
    out of the loop)
    myblock.erase(myblock.begin() + randnum);
    }
Vector<MenuItem*> spriteBtns;
std::string imgName;
for (int i = 0; i <= m + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= n + 1; j++) {
        if (i == start.x && j == start.y) {
            imgName = "general.png";
        }else if(G[i][j] == NOTHING) {
            imgName = "nud.png";
        }
        else if(i == m + 1 && j == n + 1) {
            imgName = "image/evidence.png";
        }
        else {
            imgName = "bamboo.png";
            
        }
        auto btnSprite = MenuItemImage::create(imgName,imgName);
        Size cts = btnSprite->getContentSize();
        btnSprite->setPosition(i*cts.width,j*cts.height);
        spriteBtns.pushBack(btnSprite);
    }
}

mazeMenu = Menu::createWithArray(spriteBtns);
addChild(mazeMenu);
mazeMenu->setPosition(30,80);

_player = Sprite::create("general.png");
_player->setPosition(90, 130);
this->addChild(_player);

_door = Sprite::create("image/evidence.png");
_door->setPosition(900,630);
this->addChild(_door);


// Keyboard event monitoring 
auto keyListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
keyListener->onKeyPressed = CC_CALLBACK_2(MazeScene::onKeyPressed, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyListener, this);
}

void MazeScene::onReset() {
initMap();
}
void MazeScene::changeScene(float dt) {
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionSlideInT::create(3.0f, 
MenuScene::createScene()));
}
void MazeScene::update(float dt) {
life--;
if (_player->getBoundingBox().intersectsRect(_door->getBoundingBox())) {
    initMap();
    i++;
}

if (life<=0) {
    GameOver();
    this->scheduleOnce(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(MazeScene::changeScene), 5.0);
}
if (i == 3 && life > 0) {
    UserDefault->setIntegerForKey("step4", 4);
    UserDefault->flush();
    Success();
    this->scheduleOnce(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(MazeScene::changeScene), 5.0);
  }
}
void MazeScene::GameOver() {

this->unscheduleAllCallbacks();
AudioEngine::play2d("music/over.mp3", false, 0.3);
AudioEngine::stopAll();
auto sprite = Sprite::create("image/over2.png");
auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + 
 origin.y));
this->addChild(sprite, 10);
}
void MazeScene::Success() {

this->unscheduleAllCallbacks();
AudioEngine::play2d("music/victory.mp3", false, 0.3);
AudioEngine::stopAll();
auto sprite = Sprite::create("image/success2.png");
auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + 
 origin.y));
this->addChild(sprite, 10);
 }

void MazeScene::onKeyPressed(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) {
log("Key with keycode %d pressed", keyCode);
switch (keyCode) {
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_D:
{   
    auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(0.5f, Vec2(25, 0));
    _player->runAction(Sequence::create(moveBy, nullptr));
    break;
}
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_A:
{
    auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(0.5f, Vec2(-25, 0));
    _player->runAction(Sequence::create(moveBy, nullptr));
    break;
}
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W:
{
    auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(0.5f, Vec2(0, 25));
    _player->runAction(Sequence::create(moveBy, nullptr));
    break;
}
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_S:
{
    auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(0.5f, Vec2(0, -25));
    _player->runAction(Sequence::create(moveBy, nullptr));
    break;
}
default:
    break;
}
}
void MazeScene::FindBlock() {
//find Find nearby walls 
if (x_num + 1 <= m && G[x_num + 1][y_num] == WALL) {//down
    myblock.push_back(block(x_num + 1, y_num, down));
}
if (y_num + 1 <= n && G[x_num][y_num + 1] == WALL) {//right
    myblock.push_back(block(x_num, y_num + 1, right));
}
if (x_num - 1 >= 1 && G[x_num - 1][y_num] == WALL) {//up
    myblock.push_back(block(x_num - 1, y_num, up));
}
if (y_num - 1 >= 1 && G[x_num][y_num - 1] == WALL) {//left
    myblock.push_back(block(x_num, y_num - 1, left));
}
}
```

Comment: Concentrate on one piece at time. If you want a solvable maze, there are algorithms for that, all readily available with a couple of searches in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks! I think, the most piece I want to solve is that a sprite can cross the wall, I really have no idea. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.